# RxPY buffer example using a closing selector function?

Tags: python, reactivex, rx-py

Looking for an example using RxPy where buffering is done with the use of a closing selector function to decide when to close the buffer.  In my example I want to be able to close my buffer boundaries based on values seen in the observables data itself.  I am assuming using a closing selector is the way to do this.